# Accessing data in an array of object for a map in React

Tags: api, reactjs, axios

```
"data": {
 "offset": 0,
 "limit": 20,
 "total": 1,
 "count": 1,
 "results": [
   {
    "id": 1009144,
    "name": "A.I.M.",
    "modified": "2013-10-17T14:41:30-0400",
    "thumbnail": {
      "path": "i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/6/20/52602f21f29ec",
      "extension": "jpg"
    },
    "resourceURI": "gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1009144",
    "comics": {
      "available": 33,
      "collectionURI": "gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1009144/comics",
      "items": [
        {
          "resourceURI": "gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/36763",
          "name": "Ant-Man & the Wasp (2010) #3"
        },
        {
          "resourceURI": "gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/17553",
          "name": "Avengers (1998) #67"
        }
     ]
   }
  }
]
}
```

I  am using axios to fetch datas from an api inside a React component. I would like to access to the key items in my json response in order to setState but I can't.

```
export default class Hero extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    details : [],
    comics :[]
};
}
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(infoUrl).then((res) => {
    this.setState({details : res.data.data.results,
                    comics : res.data.data.results.results[6].items});
})
}
render() {  

     (<div>
      </div>)
}   
}
```

I can access to my state details but not the comics one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results array contains only one item, so you need to use index `0` instead of `6`. Another thing is `items` is present inside `comics`, so first access `comics` then access `items`, use this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(infoUrl).then((res) => {
    this.setState({
            details : res.data.data.results,
            comics : res.data.data.results[0].comics.items});
     })
}
```

Run this snippet:

```js
let data = {"data": {
 "offset": 0,
 "limit": 20,
 "total": 1,
 "count": 1,
 "results": [
   {
    "id": 1009144,
    "name": "A.I.M.",
    "modified": "2013-10-17T14:41:30-0400",
    "thumbnail": {
      "path": "i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/6/20/52602f21f29ec",
      "extension": "jpg"
    },
    "resourceURI": "gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1009144",
    "comics": {
      "available": 33,
      "collectionURI": "gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1009144/comics",
      "items": [
        {
          "resourceURI": "gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/36763",
          "name": "Ant-Man & the Wasp (2010) #3"
        },
        {
          "resourceURI": "gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/17553",
          "name": "Avengers (1998) #67"
        }
     ]
   }
  }
 ]
 }
}
console.log('items', data.data.results[0].comics.items)
```

Answer (score 1):

`items` being present in `comics` is not the `6th` item in the result array but the `6th` item in the `first object` of the result array and hence you need to access it like.

```
res.data.data.results[0].comics.items
```

Change you componentDidMount function to

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(infoUrl).then((res) => {
    this.setState({details : res.data.data.results,
                    comics : res.data.data.results[0].items});
    })
}
```